# Animate autoLayout constraints doesn't work on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout, constraints

I have an UIButton that has only 4 constraints related to its height,width, top, left.
When the user tap on the button i update its top constraint by adding a constant value like this

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    [self updateMyButtonConstraints];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];

-(void)updateMyButtonConstraints {
   myTopButtonConstraint.constant = 10;
}
```

When i run my app on iOS 8 its works like a charm, but on iOS 7 the constraint animation doesn't work, the button basically moves from point a to point b without any animation

PS : i tried to put the update constraint instruction before starting the animation and its didn't work too

How can i do to fix this ? What i'm doing wrong ? thank you for the help

Comment: Try to call setNeedsLayout and then layoutIfNeeded right on button not on self.view

Comment: i tried it, doesn't work too :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing things in the wrong order, and you're forgetting to notify the layout system that layout is needed. Like this:

```
[self updateMyButtonConstraints];
[self.view setNeedsLayout]; // not "layoutIfNeeded"!
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

In my tests, that animates in iOS 7, iOS 8, and iOS 9. If it doesn't work for you, you're doing something else that you have not revealed.

Comment: Note that this assumes that `self.view` is the superview of the button. If not, change the code accordingly: it is the button's superview that you want to be talking to here.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version is here.

```
self.updateMyButtonConstraints()
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```